# How to submit a form embedded within Folium HTML Popup in python

Tags: python, django, iframe, folium

I am developing a web app in Django/Folium/Python to add markers to the map and I want to click on the marker and a popup appears with a form to be filled out and submitted. I have successfully developed that app but the submission does not work. If I add the URL inside the code it gives me this error: Encountered unknown tag 'url'

This is my code in Python:

```
def monitoring(request, pk):
map = folium.Map(location=[lat, lng], zoom_start=15)

html = f"""<form action="{% url 'index' %}" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="form-group">
<label for="note heading">Note heading</label>
<input type="text" name='note_heading' class="form-control">
</div>
    
<input type="hidden" name="lat" value="${lat}">
<input type="hidden" name="lng" value ="${lng}">
    
<div class="form-group">
<label for="note">Note</label>
<textarea class='form-control' name="note_des" >Enter note here</textarea>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>`
"""
iframe = folium.IFrame(html, width=200, height=200)
popup = folium.Popup(iframe)  # , max_width=100)
marker = folium.Marker([lat, lng], popup, draggable=True).add_to(map)
map = map._repr_html_()

context = {"lat": lat, "lng": lng, "map": map}
return render(request, "maps/monitoring.html", context)
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're encountering is due to mixing Django template tags (`{% %}`) with Python f-strings (`f""`). The Django template tags are not recognized when
You can modify your code like think, I think it should work :

```py
from django.urls import reverse

def monitoring(request, pk):
    map = folium.Map(location=[lat, lng], zoom_start=15)
    
    url = reverse('index')  # Get the URL for the 'index' view

    html = f"""
    <form action="{url}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="note_heading">Note heading</label>
            <input type="text" name="note_heading" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <input type="hidden" name="lat" value="{lat}">
        <input type="hidden" name="lng" value="{lng}">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="note">Note</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="note_des">Enter note here</textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
    """

    iframe = folium.IFrame(html, width=200, height=200)
    popup = folium.Popup(iframe)
    marker = folium.Marker([lat, lng], popup, draggable=True).add_to(map)
    map = map._repr_html_()

    context = {"lat": lat, "lng": lng, "map": map}
    return render(request, "maps/monitoring.html", context)
```

used inside an f-string.

Comment: Now, there is no error, but the form does not submit. When you check/view the frame source, you will see this: <form action="/maps/printing/" method="POST"> but it is not working. Any idea please? thanks,

Comment: 1_ Verify the URL pattern: Make sure you have the correct URL pattern defined for the '/maps/printing/' endpoint in your Django urls.py file. Double-check that the URL pattern matches the action attribute in your form.

2_ Ensure the POST method is allowed: Check your Django view for the '/maps/printing/' endpoint (index view) and ensure that it allows the POST method. You can use the request.method attribute to handle different HTTP methods.

Comment: Nothing was changed. It did not work. regards,

Answer (score 0):

in the third line of your python function, you have to write url_for('index') instead of url 'index'
This is the reason for the error

Comment: First thank you for your reply. I tried your solution but did not work. The form does not submit. I tried to have a local variable like this :                      form_action_url = "{% url_for('users') %}"
html = f"""<form action="{ form_action_url }" method="POST"> but it gives same error:  Encountered unknown tag 'url_for'. Any idea please? thanks.